# Replacement for "PBYR 1035B" Schottky rectifier diode

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to repair an old motherboard with a dead MOSFET and PWM controller, and I figured I'd better replace both MOSFETs, the PWM controller and this "PBYR 1035B" Schottky rectifier diode (TO-263 package).

The problem is that I can't seem to find a replacement that I can buy in my country (I'm from Romania). I've found [this DSTB2045C](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/DSTB2045C?qs=%252BC9Bk%2FBEkFxGC2P%252BHpUaKQ%3D%3D) on mouser.com which seems to have similar/higher specs, but with a minimum order quantity of 24k pcs, it's obviously out of reach.

Can anyone recommend another potential suitable replacement that I might be missing, one that is easier to buy either on TME.eu or mouser.com?

[image: PBYR 1035B]

Comment: Surely Digikey can deliver to Romania? DSTB2045C, 1564 pcs in stock, MOQ = 1 pcs.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the delivery price for orders below ~50 euros is quite steep (~ 20 euros), so I've never used it. Ideally, I would prefer TME.eu, which has the best delivery prices in my region, but they don't seem to have any compatible replacement...

Answer (score 3):

ST's [STPS1045B](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/389/stps1045b-1851399.pdf) is in stock at lcsc.com and Mouser.com and has similar specs except pin 1 is tied to pin 3 rather than NC. You could lift pin 1 if it goes somewhere on your PCB.

[image]

Comment: It is also available at TME.

Comment: Thank you. This one would be great, unfortunately it's in DPAK / TO-252 packaging (I also found quite a few of these), but they're significantly smaller than the original TO-263 diode, and I would prefer to preserve the original aspect of the motherboard (don't ask, I'm crazy).

Comment: Ah, missed that. The SOT404 designation on the NXP datasheet..